# Tail Call Optimization in Go

Tags: go, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Does the Go programming language, as of now, *optimize tail calls*? If not, does it at least optimize tail-recursive calls of a function to itself?

Comment: If I follow https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/iveUW_2--cI, not really

Comment: You could test it out by writing a tail-recursive function, then writing its iterative equivalent and comparing memory usage.

Comment: Tail call elimination isn't really an optimisation. Since turning it off changes the run-ability of a program.

Comment: No they are not going to do it https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22624

Answer (score 20):

Everything you can find over the Internet, that "Go supports tailable recursions in some cases", and that was told in [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/0oIZPHhrDzY/2nCpUZDKZAAJ):

> It is already there in 6g/8g for certain cases, and in gccgo somewhat
>   more generally.
>
> We do not currently plan to change the language to require that
>   compilers implement tail call optimization in all cases.  If you must
>   have a tail call, you use a loop or a goto statement.

To get those cases you'd better dig into [golang source](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/), which is open.

Comment: You cannot replace all tail calls by loops or gotos.

Comment: @райтфолд: Technically you can, but it would get ugly if you have to rewrite the code to be all in one function.

Comment: You can always implement tail calls in code with trampolines, but that requires doing a global rewrite and to write code in a monad pattern which is even harder without generics (though Go is getting them in 2022).

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote a new library to deal with this restriction. Thanks to the new generics language feature comes with Go 1.18.
Now, type safe stackless mutually recursive functions are possible.

https://github.com/kandu/go_tailcall

Comment: Please be sure to read [Stack Overflow's self-promotion policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) when referencing your own content.

Answer (score 4):

Extending @Rostyslav's excellent answer. If you must have a tail call, (in this example a tail recursive call) you can do something like this.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func tail(i int) {
    if i == 0 {
        return
    } else {
        fmt.Println(i)
        tail(i - 1) //tail recursive call
    }
}
func main() {
    tail(3) //3, 2, 1
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not. Nor is there any plan to according to the core development team on the mailing list.

Comment: that still the case?