# GO - switch statement in a recursive function

Tags: for-loop, recursion, go, switch-statement

I have an algorithm that I'm trying to implement but currently I have absolutely no clue how to do so, from a technical perspective.

We have a slice of 5 floats:

`mySlice := [float1, float2, float3, float4, float5]`

And a switch statement:

```
aFloat := mySlice[index]

switch aFloat {
  case 1:
    {
       //do something 
    }
  case 2:
    {
       //do something 
    }
  case 3:
    {
       //do something 
    }
  case 4:
    {
       //do something 
    }
  case 5:
    {
       //do something 
    }
  default:
    {
       //somehow go back to slice, take the next smallest and run
       //through the switch statement again
    }
}
```

What I want to do is as follows:

1. identify the smallest element of mySlice ex: `smallestFloat`
2. run `smallestFloat` through the switch statement
3. if `smallestFloat` gets to default case take the next smallest float from mySlice
4. do step 2 again.

I've managed to do the first step with a for loop and step 2, but I'm stuck on steps 3 and 4. I don't have an idea at the moment on how I might go about re-feeding the next smallest float from mySlice to the switch statement again...

I would appreciate any light shed on my problem.

EDIT: I figured that it would be good to put my solution to the algorithm presented above.

1. create another slice which will be a sorted version of mySlice
2. create a map[int]value where the index will correspond to the position of the value in the non-sorted slice, but the items of the map will be inserted in the same order as the sorted slice.

Result: a value sorted map with the respective indexes corresponding to the position of the original non-sorted slice

Comment: A map is not an ordered structure. And there is no guarantee that the keys are in the same order between different iterations of the same map.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'll keep an eye out for that

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using a Minimum Priority Queue. The original input slice of floats is not changed. It can be run on the [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/5lR8gmb7FL)

*Note*: When dealing with recursive functions, you need to be weary of stack overflows.
Go does tail recursion optimizations only in limited cases. For more information on that,
refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116644/357705).

This particular example does even better than amortized O(log N) time, because it does not have to resize the priority queue halfway through. This makes it guaranteed O(log N).

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    slice := []float64{2, 1, 13, 4, 22, 0, 5, 7, 3}
    fmt.Printf("Order before: %v\n", slice)

    queue := NewMinPQ(slice)

    for !queue.Empty() {
        doSmallest(queue)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Order after: %v\n", slice)
}

func doSmallest(queue *MinPQ) {
    if queue.Empty() {
        return
    }

    v := queue.Dequeue()

    switch v {
    case 1:
        fmt.Println("Do", v)
    case 2:
        fmt.Println("Do", v)
    case 3:
        fmt.Println("Do", v)
    case 4:
        fmt.Println("Do", v)
    case 5:
        fmt.Println("Do", v)
    default:
        // No hit, do it all again with the next value.
        doSmallest(queue)
    }
}

// MinPQ represents a Minimum priority queue.
// It is implemented as a binary heap.
//
// Values which are enqueued can be dequeued, but will be done
// in the order where the smallest item is returned first.
type MinPQ struct {
    values  []float64 // Original input list -- Order is never changed.
    indices []int     // List of indices into values slice.
    index   int       // Current size of indices list.
}

// NewMinPQ creates a new MinPQ heap for the given input set.
func NewMinPQ(set []float64) *MinPQ {
    m := new(MinPQ)
    m.values = set
    m.indices = make([]int, 1, len(set))

    // Initialize the priority queue.
    // Use the set's indices as values, instead of the floats
    // themselves. As these may not be re-ordered.
    for i := range set {
        m.indices = append(m.indices, i)
        m.index++
        m.swim(m.index)
    }

    return m
}

// Empty returns true if the heap is empty.
func (m *MinPQ) Empty() bool { return m.index == 0 }

// Dequeue removes the smallest item and returns it.
// Returns nil if the heap is empty.
func (m *MinPQ) Dequeue() float64 {
    if m.Empty() {
        return 0
    }

    min := m.indices[1]

    m.indices[1], m.indices[m.index] = m.indices[m.index], m.indices[1]
    m.index--
    m.sink(1)
    m.indices = m.indices[:m.index+1]
    return m.values[min]
}

// greater returns true if element x is greater than element y.
func (m *MinPQ) greater(x, y int) bool {
    return m.values[m.indices[x]] > m.values[m.indices[y]]
}

// sink reorders the tree downwards.
func (m *MinPQ) sink(k int) {
    for 2*k <= m.index {
        j := 2 * k

        if j < m.index && m.greater(j, j+1) {
            j++
        }

        if m.greater(j, k) {
            break
        }

        m.indices[k], m.indices[j] = m.indices[j], m.indices[k]
        k = j
    }
}

// swim reorders the tree upwards.
func (m *MinPQ) swim(k int) {
    for k > 1 && m.greater(k/2, k) {
        m.indices[k], m.indices[k/2] = m.indices[k/2], m.indices[k]
        k /= 2
    }
}
```

Comment: I've applied this method and it isn't what I need. I need each element of the slice to remain in it's original position. As mentioned in my algorithm i need to `identify` the smallest and retrieve the value, not modify the indexes of the elements.

Comment: In that case, I would look into the Priority Queue I mentioned in the answer. It can be constructed using the list indices as values. This way your slice can remain as-is, but you still get to find the smallest float in amortized O(log n) time. Whereas just looping over the slice each time is O(N) time.