# Does Go have an "infinite call stack" equivalent?

Tags: node.js, recursion, go, callstack

I'm a newbie to Go, coming from Node.JS.

In Node, if I run this:

```
function run(tick = 0) {
  if (tick < 1000000) {
    return run(tick + 1);
  }

  return 0;
}

console.log(run());
```

The program will crash because the maximum call stack size was exceeded.

If I do this in Go:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func run(tick int) (int) {
    if (tick < 1000000) {
        return run(tick + 1)
    }

    return 0
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(run(0))
}
```

This will run and print `0` to stdout.

My questions are:

- Is there a maximum number of calls above which the Go example I gave would fail?
- Is code like this an anti-pattern in Go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tail Call Optimization in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102675/tail-call-optimization-in-go)

Comment: *Is code like this an anti-pattern in Go?* Is recursion an anti-pattern?

Comment: @TimCooper: It is when the depth is not known and stack size is limited.  OP gave one such example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Go, goroutines do not have a fixed stack size. Instead they start small (with like 4KB), and grow / shrink when needed, seemingly giving the feeling of an "infinite" stack (of course it can't be truly infinite).

Yes, there is a limit. But this limit does not come from a call depth limit, but rather the stack memory limit. This limit is enforced by the Go runtime, but it is usually hundreds of MBs (or even a GB). On the Go Playground it's 250MB, which can be seen on this [Go Playground Example](https://play.golang.org/p/XzZsmGLgIp).

On my local Linux 64-bit machine it's 1 GB.

Recommended reading: [Dave Cheney: Why is a Goroutine's stack infinite?](https://dave.cheney.net/2013/06/02/why-is-a-goroutines-stack-infinite)

Returning to your example: increasing the max recursion call to `1e9` will run out of the stack:

```
if (tick < 1000000000) { ... }
```

This will result in:

```
runtime: goroutine stack exceeds 1000000000-byte limit
fatal error: stack overflow

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4b4730, 0xe)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:619 +0x81
runtime.newstack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/stack.go:1054 +0x71f
runtime.morestack()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:480 +0x89

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.run(0xffffde, 0x0)
        /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:5 +0x62 fp=0xc440088370 sp=0xc440088368 pc=0x483262
main.run(0xffffdd, 0x0)
        /home/icza/gows/src/play/play.go:7 +0x36 fp=0xc440088390 sp=0xc440088370 pc=0x483236
main.run(0xffffdc, 0x0)
...
```